# diary note 2 wont charge or connect via computer

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-2

Hi all note 2 wont suddenly turned off and will not accept charge any thoughts.., I have replaced the battery and tried hard and soft boots but no success, I have also disconnected the start switch inside and tried to supply power again, I know that it is getting charge through to battery but does not show led on phone to say so.
    I think the motherboard is fried any other ideas before I call it quits.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried changing the USB cable? Or try a different charger?

Comment: Possibly the USB connector is damaged, or may have debris, lint...